# rxjs inner native map is exiting early

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

So let's say there is an endpoint that returns things of the structure:

```
{
  results: [
    {hoofed: {
      //animal1
      }
    },
    {feline: {
      //animal2
    }},
    {other: {
      //animal3
    }}
  ]
}
```

Say I have something like so:

```
import {RxHR} from '@akanass/rx-http-request'

return RxHR.get('www.third_party.com')
  .pluck('body')
  .map(JSON.parse)
  .pluck('results')
  .map((animals) => animals.map((animal) => animal['hoofed'] || animal['feline']))
```

I would expect this to have the following behaviour:

1) Extract the response body.

2) parse the JSON

3) Extract all results

4) Pull the values at either hoofed or feline keys producing:

```
[animal1, animal2]
```

Instead, this only returns the first item to match one of the conditions,e.g. `[animal1]` rather than mapping the array onto another array as I would expect. My question is, why? And how can I achieve such an inner transformation?

Comment: What do you want as result ? Can you add an object to describe it ?

Comment: Described in more depths what I would have expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something generic in case you have an unknown number of animals :

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

// simulate exactly how we'll receive the HTTP response
const mockedData = JSON.stringify({
  body: JSON.stringify({
    results: [{
      hoofed: {
        name: 'animal1'
      }
    }, {
      feline: {
        name: 'animal2'
      }
    }, {
      other: {
        name: 'animal3'
      }
    }]
  })
});

// mock the RxHR lib and return the equivalent of an HTTP request with observable.of and delay
const RxHR = {
  get: (url) => Observable.of(mockedData).delay(1000)
};

// take an HTTP response and return the body
const resToJson = (res) => {
  const fullRes = JSON.parse(res);
  const body = JSON.parse(fullRes.body);
  return body;
};

// for a given array of objects (1), having other objects(2) as value
// return an array of objects(2)
const flattenObjects = (objArr) => objArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(curr);
  keys.forEach(key => acc.push(curr[key]));
  return acc;
}, []);

// nicely display the output : debug only
const niceOutput = (obj) => console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

const animals$ = RxHR
  .get('www.third_party.com')
  .map(resToJson)
  .map(json => json.results)
  .map(flattenObjects);

animals$
  .do(niceOutput)
  .subscribe();
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "name": "animal1"
  },
  {
    "name": "animal2"
  },
  {
    "name": "animal3"
  }
]
```

If you want to try it out, here's a working Plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/UkjfSrgHKoS3kqXwiYXA?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your stream would return sth like `[animal1, animal2, undefined]`. The stream lacks filter operator.

```
const flatAnimal = animal => animal['hoofed'] || animal['feline']

Rx.Observable.of(results)
  .map(JSON.parse)
  .map((animals) => animals.filter(flatAnimal).map(flatAnimal))
```

or you can work with the array as an observable sequence

```
Rx.Observable.of(results)
  .flatMap(JSON.parse)
  .filter(flatAnimal)
  .map(flatAnimal)
  .toArray()
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/3u43176d/